# What's practical purpose of cursorLoader?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursor, android-cursorloader

I saw some articles about `CursorLoader` like [this](https://d.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader), but I still don't understand the particular purpose of using it.

I developed apps with SQL and cursor retrieving. The point is it was very fast. I queried and parsed cursor with >500 record and 8 columns by a few millisecond. So didn't notice any delay event on old phones. So why do I need to use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [`CursorLoader`](https://d.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader) is used ostensibly to query a [`ContentProvider`](https://d.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers) with [`LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>`](https://d.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks).

There are two things that you need to keep in mind for understanding the `CursorLoader`:

- It loads data on a separate thread.
- It monitors the underlying data source for updates, re-querying when changes are detected.

Now coming to the `LoaderManager`. Simply stated, the `LoaderManager` is responsible for managing one or more `Loader`s associated with an `Activity` or `Fragment`. Each `Activity` and each `Fragment` has exactly one `LoaderManager` instance that is in charge of starting, stopping, retaining, restarting, and destroying its `Loader`s. These events are sometimes initiated directly by the client, by calling `initLoader()`, `restartLoader()`, or `destroyLoader()`. Just as often, however, these events are triggered by major `Activity`/`Fragment` lifecycle events. For example, when an `Activity` is destroyed, the `Activity` instructs its `LoaderManager` to destroy and close its `Loader`s (as well as any resources associated with them, such as a `Cursor`).

The `LoaderManager` does not know how data is loaded, nor does it need to. Rather, the `LoaderManager` instructs its `Loader`s when to start/stop/reset their load, retaining their state across configuration changes and providing a simple interface for delivering results back to the client.

So you see, all this is not easily possible when you use a simple `AsyncTask` and query an SQLite database. This is why the framework provides `CursorLoader` and `LoaderManager`:

- To perform queries on a separate thread.
- To monitor the data source for changes and update the UI.
- To integrate easily with the life cycle of `Activity` and `Fragment`.

Answer (score 1):

The practical purpose is simply how Android handles UI elements (that is on the main thread). Basically, anything that **may** be a long running process, run it in a background thread so you don't lockup the main thread. This can't be said enough. After Gingerbread this has been more enforced by Android itself. Check out [SQL helper](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html#DbHelper). To get to the point in regards to opening an SQLite connection and its "speed":

> Because they can be long-running, be sure that you call getWritableDatabase() or getReadableDatabase() in a background thread, such as with AsyncTask or IntentService.

By using `CursorLoader`, it makes your life easier if you need `ContentResolver` and are using SQLite DB. More importantly, it runs on the background. Just because you've never seen the DB lock up doesn't mean it doesn't happen. Better safe than sorry, and the main thread will thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`CursorLoader`](https://d.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/CursorLoader) from Support Library to run asynchronous queries in the background. In this way, you ensure that data loading does not cause “Application Not Responding” messages.

Answer (score 0):

A CursorLoader runs a asynchronous query in the background against a ContentProvider and then it returns the result back to the Activity or the Fragment from where it is called. 
The main advantage is that it helps the user to interact with Activity or Fragment while the query is still running in the background.